# Keyword with multiple parents

Tags: cme, keyword

The official SDL docs and the CME state/show that a keyword can have "parent keyword**s**" (multiple), also, I've read about that from various sources, and it's even explicitly mentioned in a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191010/keyword-path-in-sdl-tridion). Despite all that, I am unable to add multiple parents to a keyword from the CME, so I'm wondering if it's possible at all? I can imagine doing it via code.

I have no practical reason why I would want this, I'm just being curious.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're correct, keywords can have multiple parents, but it cannot be done through the CME. It can be done in code e.g. using Core Service